# How to prove Trigonometry equation?

Tags: trigonometry

how to solve following equation

$$
\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) + \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)
=
\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)
$$
How to prove the above equation?

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: I was trying with tana+tanb formula but not able to convert it

Comment: One problem is of course that the equation is wrong.

Comment: There may be a mistake in the equation

Comment: *Disprove${}{}{}$

Comment: Why u Disprove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
\begin{align}
&\tan\pars{\overbrace{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)}^{\ds{\equiv\ x}}}
=
\tan\pars{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) + \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)}
=
{1/4 + 1/9 \over 1 - \pars{1/4}\pars{1/9}} = {13 \over 35}
\end{align}
$$
\tan\pars{x} = {\root{1 - \cos^{2}\pars{x}} \over \cos\pars{x}}
=
{\root{1 - \pars{3/5}^{2}} \over 3/5} = {4/5 \over 3/5} = {4 \over 3}
\color{#0000ff}{\Huge\not=} {13 \over 35}
$$

Comment: U mean above equation wrong?

Comment: @user110715 Yes.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326334/a-question-about-the-arctangent-addition-formula) or Ex$\#5$  of Page $\#276$ of [this](https://archive.org/details/planetrigonomet00lonegoog)  $$\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y=\tan^{-1}\frac{x+y}{1-xy}$$ if $xy<1$

Now, as the [principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) of $\tan$ lies $\in\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right],$

If $\displaystyle \tan^{-1}z=\theta,\tan\theta=z,$
$\displaystyle\cos\theta=+\frac1{\sqrt{1+z^2}}$

Comment: how u made cosQ like that?

Comment: @user110715, $\sec^2\theta=1+\tan^2\theta,$ right?

Answer (score 0):

After you apply the formula, let $cos \theta= \frac{3}{5}$. Now convert this to $tan \theta$, which is trivial, and compare both sides.