# proving $\tan^{-1} \left( \frac{x}{1-x^2} \right) = \tan^{-1}x + \tan^{-1}(x^3)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Two related questions, one easy, one just a bit harder:

1) Prove the identity
$$
\tan^{-1} \left( \frac{x}{1-x^2} \right) =
\tan^{-1}x + \tan^{-1}(x^3)
$$

2) Now try to find a geometric or trigonometric proof of that same geometry, without resorting to calculus.

I'll post an answer to both questions in a couple of days if nobody has one yet.

Comment: for 1), just take the tangent of both sides, and use the sum formula for tangent...

Comment: I agree with the above comment, it should count as a trignonometric proof to use the tangent sum formula.

Comment: let me be clear: I don't mean that one should *assume* the desired identity, and then take the tangent of both sides in order to deduce it, which would be circular. my comment was meant as a hint that the sum formula tangent will be helpful... (as heropup has now spelled out).

Comment: of related interest: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326334/a-question-about-the-arctangent-addition-formula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof can be established starting from the angle addition identity $$\sin(x+y) = \sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y.$$  Then with $x = \frac{\pi}{2} - a$, $y = -b$, we get $$\cos(a+b) = \sin(\tfrac{\pi}{2} - a - b) = \cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b.$$  We then find $$\tan(x+y) = \frac{\sin(x+y)}{\cos(x+y)} = \frac{(\sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y)/(\cos x \cos y)}{(\cos x \cos y - \sin x \sin y)/(\cos x \cos y)} = \frac{\tan x + \tan y}{1 - \tan x \tan y}.$$  Now letting $u = \tan x$, $v = \tan y$, we get $$\tan(\tan^{-1} u + \tan^{-1}v) = \frac{u+v}{1-uv},$$ or $$\tan^{-1} u + \tan^{-1} v = \tan^{-1} \frac{u+v}{1-uv}.$$  Now letting $u = x$, $v= x^3$, we find $$\frac{u+v}{1-uv} = \frac{x+x^3}{1-x^4} = \frac{x(1+x^2)}{(1-x^2)(1+x^2)} = \frac{x}{1-x^2},$$ and the result immediately follows.

Comment: just to be clear, your deduction indicated by "or" (where you've just taken the inverse tangent of both sides) relies on the fact that $\tan^{-1}(\tan a)=a$, which is true only if $a\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. in particular, you're assuming $\tan^{-1}u+\tan^{-1}v=\tan^{-1}(\tan x)+\tan^{-1}(\tan y)\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: I am well aware of that.  There is no issue when we regard the inverse tangent as a multivalued mapping for the purposes of establishing the identity as it was given in the question.  In other words, if you want to be pedantic, the given identity is not strictly true for all choices of $x$ if you take the codomain of $\tan^{-1}$ to be $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$.  But since that was left out, I saw no reason to be so picky.  The identity as stated works fine for equating sets to sets (or equivalence classes, if you prefer to think of it that way).

Comment: I wasn't criticizing your answer (I upvoted it); I was just making the assumption explicit for students who want to be totally rigorous.

Answer (score 2):

**Part I:** Consider $f(x) = tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x}{1-x^2}\right) - tan^{-1}x - tan^{-1}(x^3)$, taking derivative of $f$:

$f'(x) = \dfrac{1+x^2}{1-x^2+x^4} - \dfrac{1}{1+x^2} - \dfrac{3x^2}{1+x^6} = \dfrac{(1+x^2)^2 - (1-x^2+x^4) - 3x^2}{1+x^6} = \dfrac{1+ 2x^2 + x^4 - 1 + x^2 - x^4 - 3x^2}{1+x^6} = 0$. Thus $f$ is constant on $\mathbb{R}$, and $f(x) = f(0) = 0$, and the identity follows.

Comment: I think the question says without calculus, though this method is interesting.

Comment: @tpb261: I guess this would work for Part 1, not Part 2...

Comment: @symplectomorphic I thought so, too. I was thinking as to why you specifically mentioned "Part II:"

Comment: I changed it to part I.

Answer (score 1):

Part I)

Taking the tan of the RHS, we have a form $tan(A+B)$ where $A = tan^{-1}(x)$, $B = tan^{-1}(x^3)$.
$$
tan(A+B) = \frac{tan(A)+tan(B)}{1-tan(A)*tan(B)}
= \frac{x + x^3}{1 - x^4}
= \frac{x(1 + x^2)}{(1-x^2)(1+x^2)}
= \frac{x}{1-x^2}
$$

Now the tan of LHS is also $\frac{x}{1-x^2}$.

Therefore the identity is true.

Comment: this interprets my comment too literally. you've *assumed* $a=b$ and then derived $\tan a=\tan b$, when the goal was to show $a=b$. my comment was meant more as a hint, not a direct proof strategy.

Comment: But if tan a = tan b, then a = b (with restrictions to quadrants)

Comment: yes... but as written, your proof is circular, and you haven't explained how to deduce $a=b$ from $\tan a=\tan b$.

Comment: Do you mean my second last line? I derived the tan of LHS by taking literally taking the tan of the LHS, not just by using the result from the RHS.

Comment: I think it would have been better not to refer to RHS and LHS, which makes it sound as if you're taking the given equation for granted, when you're supposed to be proving it. in other words, it would've been better to write: by the sum formula for tangent, we have $\tan(\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}(x^3))=\frac{x+x^3}{1-x^4}=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$. we also have $\tan(\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{1-x^2}))=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$. therefore $\tan(\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}(x^3))=\tan(\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{1-x^2}))$. then you can make a comment about deducing $a=b$ from $\tan a=\tan b$.

Comment: It is perfectly legitimate to refer to the LHS and the RHS in forming a proof, but I see where you're coming from.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't legitimate: I said it is misleading. the logic of your answer is not at all obvious. you leave a lot to be desired when you write "therefore the identity is true."