# Proof of an addition theorem

Tags: trigonometry

I have to prove $$\arctan(x) + \arctan(y) = \arctan\Bigl(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\Bigr)$$

Can somebody help me? I don't want you to give me the complete proof, but some start-help would be nice

Comment: Do you know the formulae for $\sin(x+y), \cos(x+y)$ and $\tan (x+y)$?

Comment: yes, but I have no idea to transform $arctan$ in that form

Comment: @Christian, This works only if $xy<1$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326334/a-question-about-the-arctangent-addition-formula

Answer (score 5):

From the formula $\tan(\alpha + \beta) = \frac{tan(\alpha) + \tan(\beta)}{1 - \tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}$, if we let $x = \tan(\alpha)$ and $y = \tan(\beta)$, then

$$ \arctan(x) + \arctan(y) = \alpha + \beta = \arctan(\frac{tan(\alpha) + \tan(\beta)}{1 - \tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}) = \arctan(\frac{x + y}{1 - xy})$$

Comment: haha, thank you. I should've known this, the previous proof I had to do was the one you used

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 3):

As the function $\arctan$ satisfies $\tan\arctan x=x$, you just need to prove that
$$
\tan(\arctan x+\arctan y)=\tan\arctan\frac{x+y}{1-xy}
$$
Just expand the left hand side with the addition formula for the tangent.