# Explanation of inverse trig euation solution

Tags: trigonometry

The equation is:
$\arctan 3 + 2\arctan2 = \pi + arccot 3$

They go on and assign $\arctan 3 = \theta$ and $\arctan2 = \phi$. Therefore, $\frac{\pi}{4}< \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$, same for $\phi$. Which I follow.

Then they use $\tan(A+B)$ formula to show that that $\tan(\theta+2\phi)=\frac{1}{3}$. Which implies that $\arctan \frac{1}{3} = \theta + 2\phi$, but apparently not so. As it implies $\pi + \arctan \frac{1}{3} = \theta + 2\phi$.

And there I am lost. I can see that when you combine the inequalities you get $$\pi+\frac{\pi}{4} < \theta + 2\phi < \pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$$

And then they go on to show that $$\theta + 2\phi = \pi + \arctan \frac{1}{3} = \pi + arccot 3$$

I do not understand where that $\pi$ is coming from there...

Comment: When $\tan x = \tan y$, then it does not follow that $x = y$, but only that $x-y = k\pi$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Here the inequalities show that $k = 1$ is the right integer.

Comment: If you were to write up this a bit more formally I would go for your answer. As I indeed know that the general solution to $\tan \theta = s$ is  $PV + n\Pi$. Therefore $\tanx = \tan(x+n\Pi)$. But  will the inequality always show a multiple of $\pi$? I have a tendency to ask before thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, $\arctan x+\text{arccot}x=\dfrac\pi2$  ([Proof](http://www.enotes.com/homework-help/prove-that-arctanx-arccotx-pi-2-194051))

So, the problem reduces to $\arctan 2+\arctan3=\dfrac{3\pi}4$

Now from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326334/a-question-about-the-arctangent-addition-formula) or Ex$\#5$  of Page $\#276$ of [this](https://archive.org/details/planetrigonomet00lonegoog),
  $$\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y=\begin{cases} \tan^{-1}\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy} &\mbox{if } xy<1 \\\pi+ \tan^{-1}\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy} & \mbox{if } xy> 1. \end{cases} $$

Finally,   the [principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) of $\displaystyle\tan$ lies $\displaystyle\in\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$