# Proove that $\arctan(x) + \arctan (y) = \arctan(\frac{x+y}{1 - xy})$

Tags: trigonometry

Proove that:
$$
\arctan(x) + \arctan(y) = \arctan(\frac{x+y}{1 - xy})
$$
when $xy \ge0$

Comment: If you put backslashes before common functions, you get the right font and spacing.  MathJax uses \arctan for the arctangent.

Comment: What have you tried?  You might think this looks like the angle addition formula for the tangent.

Comment: Hint: Compute $\tan(\arctan(x)+\arctan(y))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\tan(\arctan(x)+\arctan(y))=\frac{\tan(\arctan(x))+\tan(\arctan(y))}{1-\tan(\arctan(x))\tan(\arctan(y))}=\frac{x+y}{1-xy}$

Comment: Put $x,y=\sqrt3$ to validate the proposed equality

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going through answers given in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326334/a-question-about-the-arctangent-addition-formula), particularly the geometric interpretation. Another source could be [another topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y) dedicated solely to general porve.