# inverse trigonometry ranges

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

$$\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)=a+b\left(\arctan\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$$

Find sum of all distinct possible values of $a$ and $b$.
Also when we plot this graph and keep on changing the values of $a$ and $b$ we get different curves for different values.Is there any deeper insight for that?

Comment: Your question requires some refinements - the sum to find should allow what - a solution for x and y? A graph for xy?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326334/a-question-about-the-arctangent-addition-formula

Comment: The requirement is to find values of a and b so that the given relation holds true . Then the sum of the distinct values of those obtained .

Comment: Actually , the answer is 1 because by def. We have if xy<1, a= 0,b=1

Comment: if xy>1, x,y>0 , a=π ,b=1

Comment: If xy>1, x,y<0 a=-π ,b=1 but I was wondering if there is any other rigorous way to solve this

Comment: Do you mean $$\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)=a+b\left(\arctan{\frac{x+y}{1-xy}}\right)$$?

Answer (score 0):

If you *do* mean
$$\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)=a+b\left(\arctan\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$$
then this is easily solved. For $\lvert xy\rvert<1$, we have
$$\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)=\arctan\frac{x+y}{1-xy}$$
However, if $\lvert xy\rvert\not<1 $ then **either**
$$\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)=\pi+\arctan\frac{x+y}{1-xy}$$
or
$$\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)=-\pi+\arctan\frac{x+y}{1-xy}$$
Can you solve it now?

See [here](https://sites.google.com/site/micdestefano/mathematics/trigonometry/sum-of-arctangents) for more details.