# inverse trignometric inequality finding value for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, inverse

[image]

Find the interval of x for which the equation is satisfied

Comment: Set $y=x$ in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326334/a-question-about-the-arctangent-addition-formula

Answer (score 0):

Since divide by $0$ is not defined, $1 - x^2 \neq 0 $.

So $x \neq +1 \ \text{and}\  x \neq -1$.

Therefore $x \in (-\infty , +\infty) \setminus\{-1,1\}.$