# Is there any formula for $\operatorname{arctan}{(a+b)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Is there any formula for $$\operatorname{arctan}{(a+b)}$$
I know couple of formulas for trigonometric functions. But I don't know if such formulas exists for inverse trigonometric functions. I don't have a clue where to start with. Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following formula is well known and you can find it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326334/a-question-about-the-arctangent-addition-formula/326538#326538).
$$\arctan(a) + \arctan(b) = \arctan\left(\frac{a+b}{1-ab}\right)$$
(of course up to a multiple of $\pi$ with $ab\neq 1$). Then
$$\arctan(a+b) + \arctan(a-b) = \arctan\left(\frac{2 a}{1-a^2+b^2}\right)$$

$$\arctan(a+b) - \arctan(a-b) = \arctan\left(\frac{2 b}{1+a^2-b^2}\right)$$

Hence we have

\begin{align*}
2 \arctan(a+b)  &= \arctan\left(\frac{2 a}{1-a^2+b^2}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{2 b}{1+a^2-b^2}\right)\\[2mm]
\arctan(a+b)  &= \frac{1}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{2 a}{1-a^2+b^2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{2 b}{1+a^2-b^2}\right)
\end{align*}