# Integrating With Trig Subsitution

Tags: integration

Can someone please explain how to calculate the integral of
$\frac{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}{x}$ using trig substitution?

Comment: Think about triangles: suppose you have a triangle with sides $1$ and $x$. Then what is $\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}$ for that triangle? More specifically, to what trigonometric function does that ratio correspond?

Edit - I mean a triangle with a 90 degree angle.

Comment: So how does the final integral form look like after doing the trig sub?

Comment: Why don't you try seeing for yourself? Don't forget the substitution for $dx$.
The whole thing should be reduced to something that's easier to compute

Comment: When you have this kind of radicals (in a more general manner, say Sqrt[a^2 + x^2], a change of variable such as x = a Tan[y] is very useful. Can you continue from here ?

Comment: So far I have Integral of : $\frac{\sqrt{1 + (tan x)^2}}{tan x} *sec^2 x $ Where do i go from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In all the following, I intentionnally forget the [constant to add to every primitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_integration), in order to simplify the notations. All equalities with primitives are to be understood "up to a constant".*

Using **trigonometric functions**, and substitution $x=\tan u$ (then $\mathrm{d}x=(1+\tan^2u)\,\mathrm{d}u = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{cos^2u}$):

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x} \mathrm{d}x=\int \frac{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 u}}{\tan u} \frac{1}{\cos^2u}\mathrm{d}x=\int \frac{1}{|\cos u| \tan u} \frac{1}{\cos^2u} \mathrm{d}u$$
If $\cos u > 0$,
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x} \mathrm{d}x=\int \frac{1}{\sin u\cos^2u} \mathrm{d}u$$

Then

$$\frac{1}{\sin u\cos^2u}=\frac{1}{\cos^2u}\left(\frac{1}{\sin u} - \sin u + \sin u\right) = \frac{1}{\cos^2u}\left( \frac{1-\sin^2 u}{\sin u}+\sin u\right)$$
$$=\frac 1 {\sin u} + \frac{\sin u}{\cos^2 u}$$

And (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_trigonometric_functions))

$$\int \frac{1}{\sin u} \mathrm{d}u=\log \left|\tan \frac u 2\right|$$
$$\int \frac{\sin u}{\cos^2 u} \mathrm{d}u = \frac 1 {\cos u}$$

So

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x} \mathrm{d}x=\frac 1 {\cos u} +\log \left|\tan \frac u 2\right| = \frac 1 {\cos (\arctan x)} +\log \left|\tan \frac {\arctan x} 2\right| $$

Now $\frac{1}{\cos^2 u}=1+\tan^2 u$ thus $\frac 1{\cos (\arctan x)} = \sqrt{1+x^2}$,

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x} \mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{1+x^2} +\log \left|\tan \frac {\arctan x} 2\right| $$

Also, notice we have always $\cos u = \cos (\arctan x) > 0$ since $\arctan x \in ]-\pi/2, +\pi/2[$. Our assumption above was not too restrictive :-)

---

There is further simplification, with $\tan \frac{\arctan x}{2}$.

The idea is to write $\tan \frac{\theta}2$ as a function of $\tan \theta$, that is, reversing the [usual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula) formula $\tan \theta = \frac{2t}{1-t^2}$ where $t=\tan \frac{ \theta }2$.

That is, we want to solve

$$(1-t^2) \tan \theta -2t = 0$$
$$(\tan \theta) t^2 + 2t - \tan \theta = 0$$

It's a quadratic equation with $\Delta = 4(1+\tan^2\theta$), so the solutions are

$$t = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+\tan^2 \theta}}{\tan \theta}$$

Notice that $t = \tan \frac{\theta}{2}$ has the same sign than $\tan \theta$ for $\theta \in ]-\pi/2, \pi/2[$, so the sign in $\pm$ is actually a $+$.

$$\tan \frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 \theta}-1}{\tan \theta}$$

And

$$\tan \frac{\arctan x}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x} \mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{1+x^2} +\log \left|\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x}\right|=\sqrt{1+x^2} +\log (\sqrt{1+x^2}-1) - \log |x| $$

---

The answer can be written slightly differently:

$$\sqrt{1+x^2} -\log (\sqrt{1+x^2}+1) + \log |x|$$

It's enough to check that

$$\frac{(\sqrt{1+x^2}+1)(\sqrt{1+x^2}-1)}{|x|^2}=\frac{1+x^2-1}{x^2}=1$$

Thus, taking logarithms,
$$\log (\sqrt{1+x^2}+1) + \log (\sqrt{1+x^2}-1) - 2\log |x| =  0$$

$$\log (\sqrt{1+x^2}-1) - \log |x| = -\log (\sqrt{1+x^2}+1) + \log |x|$$

---

There is still place for a bit of simplification:

$$\log (\sqrt{1+x^2}+1) - \log |x|=\log \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}+1}{|x|}=\log \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{|x|^2}}+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)$$

You may recognize $\arg\sinh t = \log (t + \sqrt{1+t^2})$, so

$$\log (\sqrt{1+x^2}+1) - \log |x|=\arg \sinh \frac{1}{|x|}$$

Thus, as a final step, we can write

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x} \mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{1+x^2}-\arg \sinh \frac{1}{|x|}$$

---

Another solution, using **hyperbolic functions**, with substitution $x=\sinh u$ (and $\mathrm{d}x=\cosh u \,\mathrm{d}u$), using the fact that $\cosh^2 u - \sinh^2 u = 1$:

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x} \mathrm{d}x = \int \frac{\cosh u}{\sinh u} \cosh u \,\mathrm{d}u= \int \frac{1+\sinh^2u}{\sinh u} \mathrm{d}u$$
$$=\int \left(\frac{1}{\sinh u}+\sinh u\right) \mathrm{d}u$$

And, with the [usual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_hyperbolic_functions) $\int \frac 1 {\sinh u} \,\mathrm{d}u = \frac 1 2\log|\tanh \frac u 2|$,

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x} \mathrm{d}x=\frac 1 2\log\left|\tanh \frac u 2\right| + \cosh u = \frac 1 2\log\left|\tanh \frac {\arg \sinh x} 2\right| + \cosh (\arg \sinh x)$$
$$=\sqrt{1+x^2} + \frac 1 2\log\left|\tanh \frac {\arg \sinh x} 2\right|$$

Like with the first solution, it would be possible to simplify further.

Comment: Nice work (+1). In *Mathematica* I have precisely $\sqrt{x^2+1}-\log \left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+1\right)+\log (x)$ Double check signs.

Comment: @arbautjc. Very nice work ! +1. Cheers.

Comment: @J.W.Perry. I agree with your result.

Comment: Ok, it's the same actually. And Mathematica should have put absolute value in $\log x$, but it's the kind of abuse to be expected from a CAS (Maxima does the same)

Comment: The inverse half angle formula has been explained here (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592498/to-show-inverse-of-tan-x/592545#592545)