# Simplifying an Arctan equation

Tags: trigonometry

Simplify $f(x)=Arctan(x)+Arctan(\frac{1}{x})$.

**My attempt**

For all non null real numbers $f$ is derivable and is odd:

so for all non null real number x : $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}-\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}=0$ . So $f$ is constant on $\mathbb{R^{\star}}$ so $f(x)=f(1)=2Arctan(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and since $f$ is odd then $f(-x)=-f(x)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ so this is my conclusion:

$f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ if x>0 and $f(x)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ if x<0. Can someone please check my work. Thank you very much .

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138310/show-that-2-tan-12-pi-cos-1-frac35/583359#583359

Comment: Yours @Module seems not only a correct solution but also a rather nice, elegant one. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

Try $$\begin{align}\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}\frac1x&=\tan^{-1}\left(\tan\left(\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}\frac1x\right)\right)\\
&=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+\frac1x}{1-x\cdot\frac1x}\right)\\
&=\tan^{-1}(\text{sgn}(x)\infty)=\frac\pi2\text{sgn}(x)\end{align}$$

Where $\text{sgn}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}1\text{ if }x>0\\0\text{ if }x=0\\-1\text{ if }x<0\end{array}\right.$ (Note that the sum is actually undefined at $0$, but I'm saying it's $0$ for convenience.)

Alternatively, consider the geometric definition of arctangent:  Given a right-angled triangle with sides $a,b,c$ (where $c$ is a hypotenuse) and angles $A,B,C$ ($C=\frac\pi2$), $\tan^{-1}\frac ba=A$.  If we let $x=\frac ba$, then $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}\frac1x=A+B=\frac\pi2$

Your way works, too.  It's pretty clever actually.

Answer (score 1):

The derivation is perfect. Let me corroborate

Using the definition of the [principal values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values)

$\displaystyle\arctan \frac1x=\begin{cases} \text{arccot}x &\mbox{if }  x>0 \\
\text{arccot}x-\pi  & \mbox{if } x<0 \end{cases} $

See [Are $\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ and $\arctan(1/x)$ the same function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-arccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function)

and we know $\displaystyle\arctan(y)+\text{arccot}(y) =\frac\pi2$ for all real $y$ ([Proof](http://www.enotes.com/homework-help/prove-that-arctanx-arccotx-pi-2-194051))

Answer (score 0):

What does $\arctan x=\arctan\frac x1$ mean ? It means that you have a straight-edge triangle with one ‘leg’ of length *x* and the other ‘leg’ of length $1$, and your ‘arc’ or angle is the one opposite to the ‘leg’ of length *x*, whose tangent is obviously $\frac x1=x$. And what does $\arctan\frac1x$ mean ? It means that you have a straight-edge triangle with one ‘leg’ of length *x* and the other ‘leg’ of length $1$, and your ‘arc’ or angle is the one opposite to the ‘leg’ of length $1$, whose tangent is obviously $\frac1x$. In other words, your sum is the sum of the two non-straight angles of a straight-edge triangle: which is how much, exactly ? :-)