# Verify the identity: $\tan^{-1} x +\tan^{-1} (1/x) = \pi /2$

Tags: trigonometry

Verify the identity: $\tan^{-1} x + \tan^{-1} (1/x) = \frac\pi 2, x > 0$

$$\alpha= \tan^{-1} x$$

$$\beta = \tan^{-1} (1/x)$$

$$\tan \alpha = x$$

$$\tan \beta = 1/x$$

$$\tan^{-1}[\tan(\alpha + \beta)]$$

$$\tan^{-1}\left
[{\tan\alpha + \tan\beta\over 1 - \tan\alpha \tan\beta}
\right]$$

$$\tan^{-1}\left[
{x + 1/x\over 1- x/x }\right]$$

$$\tan^{-1}\left[{x + (1/x)\over 0} \right]$$

I can't find out what I'm doing wrong..

Comment: You do not have to just use LaTex for Greek letters.

Comment: Great… Thanks…  What should I use instead?

Comment: @KKendall Put the entire equation in dollar signs. use a backslash in front of trig functions like $\tan$, and put the -1 in curly braces.

Comment: You're trying to compute $\tan(\pi/2)$, which doesn't exist.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610261/simplifying-an-arctan-equation

Answer (score 15):

**Hint:** 
When you want to prove that something smooth is constant, use derivatives.

details:
if $f(x) = \arctan x + \arctan\frac 1x$ then
$$
f'(x) = \frac 1{1+x^2} + \frac 1{1+\left(\frac 1x\right)^2}\times \left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) =0
$$
then $f(x) = f(1) = 2\arctan 1 = \frac\pi 2$ on the **interval** $\{x>0\}$.

The problem of your method is that the formula you are using is true only when
$$
\alpha , \beta, \alpha + \beta \neq \frac\pi 2 \mod \pi
$$

Answer (score 9):

An easy, mostly graphical proof: $\tan\alpha=x$, $\tan\beta=\frac1x$, and $\alpha+\beta=\frac\pi2$.

[image: Triangle]

The reason you get a division by zero in the argument of arctan is that $\displaystyle\lim_{\varphi\to\frac\pi2}\tan\varphi=\pm\infty\approx\tfrac10$. So, in ***very*** informal notation, you could say that $\tan^{-1}(\infty)=\tfrac\pi2$, and that your calculation in a way make sense.

Comment: Can you also do this if $x<0$? I mean, lengths of sides of triangles are always positive... is there a way to do this argument anyway?

Comment: It's only informal if you are unfamiliar with the relevant formalism. $\arctan(\pm \infty) = \pm \pi/2$ is quite standard in real (not complex) settings as soon as one is familiar with the extended real numbers.

Answer (score 6):

You're basically trying to compute $\tan(\pi/2)$, which doesn't exist.

If you set $\beta=\arctan(1/x)$, then $\tan\beta=1/x$, that is
$$
x=\cot\beta=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta\right)
$$
Therefore
$$
\arctan x=\arctan\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta
$$
by the hypothesis that $x>0$, so that $0<\arctan(1/x)<\pi/2$.

Answer (score 5):

Assume $x>0$, then

\begin{align}&\tan^{-1} x +\tan^{-1} \dfrac1x
\\\\=&\tan^{-1} x +\tan^{-1}\dfrac1{\tan\tan^{-1} x}
\\\\=&\tan^{-1} x +\tan^{-1}\cot \tan^{-1} x
\\\\=&\tan^{-1} x +\tan^{-1}\tan(\dfrac{\pi}2- \tan^{-1}x)
\\\\=&\tan^{-1} x +\dfrac{\pi}2- \tan^{-1}x\qquad\qquad\qquad
\left(\because\text{for $x>0$,}\;\dfrac{\pi}2- \tan^{-1}x\in\left(0,\dfrac{\pi}2\right)\right)
\\\\=&\dfrac{\pi}2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

One may also use complex numbers: We are multiplying two complex numbers with argument $\frac{1}{x}$ and $x$.

So, we desire to show that $\arg((1 + ix)(x + i)) = \frac{\pi}{2}$

We expand the product to get $(x^2 + 1)i$ -- since there is no real part and the imaginary part is $> 0$, the argument is $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: This is a nice one!

Answer (score 4):

Yet another possibility:

You want $y+z$ for $y,z$ satisfying $\sin y / \cos y=\cos z/\sin z$.  Since $\sin y=\cos(\pi/2-y)$ it follows that $z=\pi/2-y$.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to that which was exposed, I want to say the following:

$\cot(\tan^{-1}x ) = \tan(\pi/2 - \tan^{-1}x)$

Let's prove it:

First, observe that $\cot(\tan^{-1}x) = \cot(\tan^{-1}x + \cot^{-1}x -\cot^{-1}x ) = \cot(\pi/2 -\cot^{-1}x) $ (I)

since $\tan^{-1}x+\cot^{-1}x = \pi/2 $ (II)

But, observe that from equation (I) and also that $\cot(\pi/2 - x) = \tan x$, that $\cot(\pi/2 -\cot^{-1}x) = \tan(\cot^{-1}x).$

Now, we conclude (II).