# Could someone explain me this "ownership" of the arctangent

Tags: trigonometry

someone could explain to me this:

$$\int { \arctan { \left( \frac { 1 }{ { u }^{ 2 } }  \right)  }  }  \,du=\int { \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  } -\arctan { \left( { u }^{ 2 } \right)  }  \, du$$

Comment: See [this](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=143695) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720517/verify-the-identity-tan-1-x-tan-1-1-x-pi-2).

Comment: What is an "ownership"?

Comment: I voted to put this on hold because it is not clear to me what is being asked.

Answer (score 3):

If you draw a right triangle with sides $a,b,c$ angle $A$ opposite leg $a$, you have $\arctan \frac ab=A, \arctan \frac ba=\frac \pi 2-A$.  The general relation then is $\arctan \frac 1x=\frac \pi 2 -\arctan x$.  The integral signs don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

$$\boxed{\tan^{-1} \dfrac 1 x = \cot^{-1}x = \dfrac {\pi} 2 - \tan^{-1} x}$$

Proof of first equality: $y = \tan^{-1} \dfrac 1 x \Rightarrow \tan y = \dfrac 1 x \Rightarrow \cot y = x \Rightarrow y = \cot^{-1} x$.

Proof of second equality: $\cot \left(\dfrac {\pi} 2 - \theta\right) = \tan \theta \Rightarrow \cot \left(\dfrac {\pi} 2 - \tan^{-1} x \right) = \tan \tan^{-1}x = x \Rightarrow \dfrac {\pi} 2 - \tan^{-1} x = \cot^{-1} x$.