# How to prove that $\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(\dfrac{1}{x})=\pi/2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How to prove that
 $$
\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(\dfrac{1}{x})=\pi/2?
$$

---

I have tried to use 
$$
\tan^{-1}(x)+\cot^{-1}(x)=\pi/2.
$$
But I do not know how to go further.

Comment: How about drawing a right triangle with base of length $1$ and height of length $x$?

Comment: 7 persons have given answers : very well ; but noone seems to know that it is a very classical question which has answers everywhere ; among many, here is a reference: (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/720517).

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-mathrmarccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: compute the derivative of $f:(0,+\infty)\longrightarrow\mathbb{R},\quad x\mapsto \tan^{-1}(x) + \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. However, I got $f'=0$, so $f=constant$. And plug in $x=1$, I got $f=\pi/2$ a,d plug in $x=-1$, I got $f=-\pi/2$. So this proof problem is not right? I also use Wolfram Alpha to plotted it out and it does show a step function.

Comment: Yes, $f$ is a constant, so it's always equal to $f(1)$, which is $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: $f' = 0$ means $f$ is constant on any interval on which it is defined. But $f$ is undefined at $0$, so it is only constant on $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)$ (and it takes different values on the different intervals).

Comment: Yes, the formula is only valid for $x>0$.

Answer (score 3):

Another way (assuming $x>0$):

$$\begin{align*}
 \arctan x+\arctan\frac1x&=
 \int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+t^2}+\int_0^{1/x}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=
 \int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+t^2}+\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}\\
 &=\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=
 \lim_{t\to\infty}\arctan(t)-\arctan(0)=
 \frac\pi2.
\end{align*}$$

We have used the change of variable $x\mapsto 1/x$ in the second integral.

Comment: For the change of variables part, why it is not from $\infty$ to $x$?

Comment: It is indeed from $\infty$ to $x$, but the derivative of $1/x$ has a minus sign, so I reversed the limits.

Answer (score 2):

I think first equality should be $\;\;\cfrac\pi2\cdot\text{sign}(x)\;$

Answer (score 0):

Presumably $x > 0$; otherwise this is false.

Hint: Write $x = \tan\theta$, with $0 < \theta < \pi/2$. Then you can rewrite the equation as
$$\tan^{-1}(1/\tan\theta) = \pi/2 - \theta$$
which (since both sides are between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$) is equivalent to
$$1/\tan\theta = \tan(\pi/2 - \theta).$$
How can you show this?

Answer (score 0):

Start with a right-angled triangle $ABC$, as shown below.

Looking at the angle $\angle BAC$ we have $\tan \theta = \frac{x}{1}$.

Looking at the angle $\angle ACB$ we have $\tan(\frac{1}{2}\pi-\theta)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Hence $\theta = \arctan x$ and $\frac{1}{2}\pi-\theta=\arctan \frac{1}{x}$, and so
$$\arctan x + \arctan \tfrac{1}{x} = \tfrac{1}{2}\pi$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

(This space intentionally left blank.)