# Relation between $\tan^{-1}(x)$ and $\cot^{-1} (x)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, inverse

Suppose we've got 
$$I_1=\int_{-1}^{1} \tan^{-1}(x) + \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ and
$$ I_2=\int_{-1}^{1} \cot^{-1}(x) + \cot^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
So how can we relate $I_1$ and $I_2$?
I know that $$ cot^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \tan^{-1}(x)$$ and $$ \tan^{-1}(x)+ \cot^{-1}(x)=π/2$$
 but is that always true?? And $I_1 = I_2$??

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610261/simplifying-an-arctan-equation

Answer (score 1):

Draw the graphs of $\arctan x$ and $\mathrm{arccot} \;x$.  That should help answer about their relation.

**edit:**  I had said

> I seem to recall that there are two sensible (but different) conventions for $\mathrm{arccot} \;x$,  with each convention used in some calculus texts.

I looked it up.  This different convention thing is for $\mathrm{arcsec}\;x$, however.