# Does $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=\text{sgn}(xy)\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Tags: trigonometry

Is it true that
$$
\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=\text{sgn}(xy)\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$? If so, I do I show it? Any hint would be useful.

Comment: What is your motivation? What is the context? Why do you think it is true?

Comment: @Sahaj I have simply tried it with multiple values. I am sure there is a straightforward way to show it. I will think about it. [This might hint at it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610261/simplifying-an-arctan-equation). I will edit the post if I get somewhere, no need to close this question.

Comment: You need to show your work and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the post you linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610261/simplifying-an-arctan-equation), we know that
$$\arctan(t)+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}\text{sgn}(t),\quad\forall t\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$$
Substituting $t=\frac{x}{y}$ with $y\neq 0$, we get that
$$\arctan\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}\text{sgn}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right),\quad\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$$
Since $\text{sgn}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=\text{sgn}\left(xy\right)$,
$$\arctan\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}\text{sgn}\left(xy\right),\quad\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$$

Comment: Easy and simple. Thank you!