# Simplify this fraction with square roots; application to arctangent equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I need your help.

I don't know how to simplify: $\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}}{2\sqrt{3}} $
and $\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}}{2\sqrt{3}}$

Thank you in advance.

I found $1$ and $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}$. Then I have to show that these are solutions of the following equation: $arctan(x)+arctan(x\sqrt{3})= \frac{7\pi}{12}$. How can I do that ?

Comment: To begin with, multiply the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt{3}$. That way, your denominator will become rational.

Comment: Thank you ! I found 1 and -1/(sqrt{3}). Then I have to show that these are solutions of the following equation: arctan(x)+arctan(x*sqrt{3})= (7pi/12).                                          How can I do that ?

Comment: Just replace $x$ in the equation $\arctan(x)+\arctan(\sqrt{3}x) = \frac{7\pi}{2}$ by the numbers you found, and verify that equality holds.

Comment: @vev78, Be careful for $\arctan$ addition. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138310/show-that-2-tan-12-pi-cos-1-frac35/583359#583359  and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

$$4+2\sqrt3=(\sqrt3)^2+1^2+2\cdot1\cdot\sqrt3=(\sqrt3+1)^2$$

Comment: Thank you !! But I never see this kind of simplification: do you have any trick to help me to see it easier ?

Comment: Here is a way that you can cheat...
Suppose that you suspect that either
$$\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}}{2\sqrt{3}}\text{ or }\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}}{2\sqrt{3}}=1$$
Equating the latter fraction with $1$ will give us $-\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{3}+1$, which is clearly impossible. So let's equate the former with $1$ instead.
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}}{2\sqrt{3}}&=&1\\
-1+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}&=&2\sqrt{3}\\
\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}&=&\sqrt{3}+1\\
4+2\sqrt{3}&=&(\sqrt{3}+1)^2\\
\end{array}$$
Now you can "see" the simplification.