# principal arguement of a complex number. principal argZ1 = a and principal argZ2=b . what will be arguement of (Z1.Z2) when a+b is greater than pi.

Tags: complex-analysis

principal argZ1 = a and principal argZ2=b . what will be arguement of (Z1.Z2) when a+b is greater than pi.According to me it should be a+b-pi but its given a+b-2 pi .

Comment: See the formula here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138310/show-that-2-tan-12-pi-cos-1-frac35/583359#583359  OR  in my answer here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523625/showing-arctan-frac23-frac12-arctan-frac125

Answer (score 1):

The argument is determined up to a multiple of $2\pi$, so if $a+b$ is too big, you have to subtract $2\pi$.

Comment: but in my question they are saying that a+b is greater than pi. that means my angle is lying in third quadrant . so accordingly i'm supposed to write a+b- π.

Comment: Then $a+b-\pi$ is an angle in the *first* quadrant, so that can't be right.

Comment: can u please elaborate..?